# Rmarkdown Pandoc error after update to macOS Catalina (10.15)

Tags: r, rstudio, r-markdown

I had a simple shell script that ran the following:

```
Rscript -e 'rmarkdown::render("index.Rmd")'
```

After updating to macOS Catalina (10.15) I started getting the following error:

```
Error: pandoc version 1.12.3 or higher is required and was not found (see the help page ?rmarkdown::pandoc_available).
```

However, if I knit `index.Rmd` directly in RStudio, it works fine. And, when I check the pandoc version I get:

```
rmarkdown::pandoc_version()
[1] ‘2.3.1’
```

But, if I run the following in terminal I get:

```
Rscript -e 'rmarkdown::pandoc_version()'
NULL
```

Again, I can knit the file directly in RStudio, but I'm curious why my shell script stopped working and if anyone knows how to fix it.

I also posted this question in the [RStudio Community here.](https://community.rstudio.com/t/rmarkdown-pandoc-error-after-update-to-macos-catalina-10-15/43507)

Answer (score 2):

@mattwarkentin posted a solution that worked for me on the [RStudio Community page](https://community.rstudio.com/t/rmarkdown-pandoc-error-after-update-to-macos-catalina-10-15/43507).

Essentially, I just needed to install Pandoc system-wide using Homebrew:

`brew install pandoc`